# Expressions with Boolean variables and simplification

Tags: boolean-computation

I have some familiarity with Mathematica, but have no experience with any Boolean computation. Suppose we have the Boolean formula $(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (x_2 \lor x_3)$. This can be simplified by applying rules of Boolean logic, as follows.

$$\begin{align}
&(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (x_2 \lor x_3) \\
&= (x_1 \land x_2) \lor (x_1 \land x_3) \lor (x_2 \land x_2) \lor (x_2 \land x_3) \\
&=x_2 \lor (x_1 \land x_2) \lor (x_2 \land x_3) \lor (x_1 \land x_3) \\
&=x_2 \lor (x_1 \land x_3)
\end{align}$$

Can formulas of Boolean variables be computed in Mathematica 9? Can Mathematica apply rules of Boolean logic to make simplifications like as shown above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

For your example, e.g., `BooleanMinimize[(x1 || x2) && (x2 || x3)]` outputs `(x1 && x3) || x2`

`FullSimplify` will also do basic simplifications on boolean constructs, but the boolean specific functions available in MM give you more options & flexibility.

You can enter the traditional characters is desired using MM character names, and get the output using traditional characters also, e.g. `BooleanMinimize[(x1 || x2) && (x2 || x3)]//TraditionalForm`

There's a nice article in the [Mathematica Journal](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2013/10/using-boolean-computation-to-solve-some-problems-from-ramsey-theory/).

Comment: You should review too `LogicalExpand` because it's very useful if you handled with logical expression. e.g In the particular example above, the outcome is the same by `BooleanMinimize`.

Comment: It works. BTW, is there a way to get Mathematica to output the result in symbols $\land$ instead of &&, and $\lor$ instead of ||?

Comment: @Identity: Just add `//TraditionalForm` to end, or enclose whatever you do in `TraditionalForm[...]` - I'll edit answer.